# Remote access from home when I'm doing a home lab

Tags: ssh, remote-access

How can I access my Ubuntu Server GUI away from my home network?

Comment: Depends on the "server gui" you installed. Example: `cockpit` uses a web-based interface, so you needn't muck about with VNC or RDP. Beyond that, you need Port Forwarding on your router, and you likely need DDNS so your external system can find the router.

Comment: Can you install Anydesk on your Ubuntu machine?? If you mean "Ubuntu with GUI" by "server GUI", then anydesk seems to be a good option.

Comment: There seem two independent questions munged together here. 1) How to get through your router: VPN or Port Forwarding. 2) How to communicate with the server: SSH, web-based GUI, and/or remote RDP/VNC/X2GO GUI. You need to do a bit more research about which options best match your intended use.

Answer (score 0):

Install and use tigervnc:

```
sudo apt install tigervnc-standalone-server
```

Then run

```
vncpasswd
```

and enter a password.

change ~/.vnc/xstartup to :

```sh
#!/bin/sh 
# Start Gnome 3 Desktop 
[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && 
   exec /etc/vnc/xstartup 
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && 
   xrdb $HOME/.Xresources vncconfig -iconic & 
   dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session &
```

then start the server with: `vncserver`.

then conext with reminna

Comment: How will this help if the OP is using Ubuntu Server which normally doesn't have a graphical interface? Also, what does "conext with reminna" mean? Do you mean _connect_? And what is "reminna"? Is that a command?

Answer (score 0):

Remmina is a simple and lightweight remote desktop client for various protocols like RDP, VNC, and SSH. Remmina is easy to use and suitable for basic remote access.

To install Remmina in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type either `sudo apt install remmina` or `sudo snap install remmina` The remmina apt package is installed by default in Ubuntu.

Remmina doesn't have a built-in method to directly handle router traversal. It relies on external mechanisms like port forwarding or VPNs to establish connections through a home router.